# Firebase chat app not displaying messages like whatsapp does

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to come up with a chat app using Firebase Recycler adapter. The problem is that the sender's and receiver's chats are not displayed as expected. All the chats are displayed on the right. Despite the text being "Morning", the text is displayed as "Hello".
Below is my code

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

import com.firebase.ui.database.SnapshotParser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import ultramodern.activity.besha.Adapter.MessageAdapter;
import ultramodern.activity.besha.Model.Chat;
import ultramodern.activity.besha.Model.Users;

public class Complete_new_Group extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button fab,paybtn, depobtn, borrowbtn, borrowicon, depoicon, payicon;
CircleImageView sendtextbutton;
EditText text_send;
RecyclerView chatrecyclerView;
MessageAdapter messageAdapter;




public static final int MESSAGE_RIGHT=0;
public static final int MESSAGE_LEFT=1;
//private String user_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete_new__group);
    Toast.makeText(this, "This area is still under development", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab_complete_group);
    paybtn = findViewById(R.id.button6);
    depobtn = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    borrowbtn = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    borrowicon = findViewById(R.id.button8);
    depoicon = findViewById(R.id.button9);
    payicon = findViewById(R.id.button10);
    sendtextbutton = findViewById(R.id.sendtextButton);
    text_send = findViewById(R.id.text_send);
    chatrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatrecycler);

    chatrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    paybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    depobtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    borrowbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    borrowicon.setOnClickListener(this);
    depoicon.setOnClickListener(this);
    payicon.setOnClickListener(this);
    sendtextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = text_send.getText().toString();
            if (!message.equals("")){
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");
                sendmessage(message,userId,firebaseUser.getUid());
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Complete_new_Group.this, "You can't send an empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            text_send.setText("");
        }
    });

    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    final String user_id;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    user_id = intent.getStringExtra("userId");
    assert user_id != null;
//    Log.d("TRACK",user_id);
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            readMessage(firebaseUser.getUid(),user_id,users.getImageURL());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view==fab){
        paybtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        depobtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        borrowbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        borrowicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        depoicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        payicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (view==paybtn){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Group_pay.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view==payicon){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Group_pay_icon_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view==depobtn){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Group_deposit_button_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view==depoicon){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Group_depo_icon_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view==borrowbtn){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Group_deposit_button_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view==borrowicon){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Group_borrow_icon_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view==sendtextbutton){


    }


}
private void sendmessage(String message,String sender, String reciever){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender",sender);
    hashMap.put("reciever",reciever);
    hashMap.put("message",message);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
}

private void readMessage(final String myId, final String userId, String imageURL){
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>().setQuery(databaseReference, new SnapshotParser<Chat>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Chat parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String message = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("message").getValue());
            String sender = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("sender").getValue());
            String receiver = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("reciever").getValue());
            return new Chat(message,sender,receiver);
        }
    }).build();
    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter  = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat,ViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull Chat chat) {
            if (chat.getReceiver().equals(userId) && chat.getSender().equals(myId) || chat.getReceiver()
                    .equals(myId) && chat.getSender().equals(userId)){
                viewHolder.showMessage.setText(chat.getMessage());
            }



        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == MESSAGE_RIGHT){
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right,parent,false);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }
            else {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left,parent,false);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            Chat chat = getItem(position);
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                return MESSAGE_LEFT;
            }
            else {
                return MESSAGE_RIGHT;
            }
            //return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }
    };
    chatrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView showMessage;
    public ImageView profilepic;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        showMessage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.showMessage);
        profilepic=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    }
    public void setText(String paramString){
        this.showMessage.setText(paramString);
    }
}

}
```

This is the output on both the sender and the receiver

[image]

I need some assistance

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 250 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: However, if you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb), where this issue is already solved.